# What is the redeclaration of variable in C?

Tags: c, gcc

When I compile the c source code with GCC, it shows the following error message:

```bash
> gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:9: error: redeclaration of ‘i’ with no linkage
    4 |     int i;
      |         ^
test.c:3:9: note: previous declaration of ‘i’ with type ‘int’
    3 |     int i;
      |
```

I'm a bit confused because I thought I'd run into a redefinition error.
I assume it is not only redefinition but also redeclaration. As far as I know, one variable can be declared repeatedly but can't be redefined.

source code:

```cpp
> cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i; // declaration and definition
    int i;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to figure out what is redeclaration error.
What's the difference between redeclaration and redefinition?

Comment: All definitions are also declarations, but not the other way around. *"one variable can be declared repeatedly"* Not in this case.

Comment: "*As far as I know, one variable can be declared repeatedly*" - not in the same scope, it can't. What makes you think it can?

Comment: 'int i;' is a definition. 'extern int i;' is a declaration.

Comment: @gast128 Are you sure?  "The line int x; both declares and defines the variable" from `https://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: One variable can be declared repeatedly in the same scope--as long as the declaration is not also a definition (e.g., `extern int i; extern int i;`): https://godbolt.org/z/PWYjdPP5h

Comment: @RemyLebeau: C also has some truly arcane rules about defining global variables. So in C, if the `int i; int i;` had been outside of `main` the code would (insanely enough) be completely legal and accepted. https://godbolt.org/z/c4zc3v98b

Comment: @gast128, No, `int i;` is both a definition and a declaration.

Comment: @YQ CUI: yes but you get the point. Not sure why you post a SO question if you already know the details.

Comment: @gast128  Because I thought I'd run into a refinition error but got a redeclaration. Why this happend? Is it because of my misunderstanding? or is there no distinction between redefinition and redeclaration in the compiler?

Comment: @YQ CUI: on VS2019 I get the following error: 'error C2086: 'int i': redefinition'

Answer (score 2):

Potayto, potahto. Non-extern declarations are also definitions. Redeclarations and redefinitions are both problems since they're the same thing for such objects. I would have said redefinition, but redeclaration is also correct, and it's the language used by the spec for the constraint being violated by your program.

> C23 §6.7.1 ¶3 If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be no more than one declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space, except that: [no relevent exception]